# sessions are getting undefined after page refresh or when requesting other routes

Tags: node.js, express, session, session-cookies

I am trying to make  user authentication with session in express.for session database I used Mysql but problem is that when trying to access session again in another route or after page refresh isAuthenticated session get value of undefined.also note that database is getting filled correctly with sessions (I am using localhost with Mysql workbanch).  here is the code

```
const session=require('express-session');

const MySQLStore = require('express-mysql-session')(session); 


const options={
connectionLimit: 10,
password:'sql123sql',
user:'root',
database:'sessions',
host:'localhost',
port: 3306,
createDatabaseTable: true
}

const sessionStore = new MySQLStore(options);


app.use(session({
secret: secret_key,
resave: false,
saveUninitialized:false,
store: sessionStore,
cookie: { secure:false,sameSite:true, httpOnly: true, maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 }, // Cookie settings
}));


app.post('/verifycode',(req,res)=>{
let inputValue=req.body.inputValue;
let email=req.body.email;
let username=req.body.username;
let password=req.body.password;

if(inputValue===''+code+'' && inputValue.length>0){
  registerUser(req,email,username,password);

  req.session.isAuthenticated=true;

 console.log(req.session.isAuthenticated);
  res.json('authorized succesfully');
}else if(inputValue!==code && inputValue.length>0){
res.send('authorized unsuccesfully');
}

console.log(code);

})


app.get('/isAuth',(req,res)=>{

if(req.session.isAuthenticated && req.session.isAuthenticated===true){
  res.send('true');
}else{
  res.send('false');
}
console.log('Is authenticated is '+req.session.isAuthenticated);
})
```